# A problem occurred evaluating project ':stripe_stripe-react-native'

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/home/kashi/React Native/taajfoodmobile/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-react-native/android/build.gradle' line: 29
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':stripe_stripe-react-native'.

> No signature of method: build_526hb1oh4bfs3lomhun33ieeh.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_526hb1oh4bfs3lomhun33ieeh$_run_closure1) values: [build_526hb1oh4bfs3lomhun33ieeh$_run_closure1@23e66cbe]

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s

Answer (score 0):

`buildFeatures` used in stripe-react-native SDK is available from Gradle plugin >= 4.x versions only.

Please refer to this GitHub issue https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/issues/203 for details.